# Adding items to a dictionary in python (nested)

Tags: python, dictionary

I know there are other several question that resembles mine but i didn't really find one that fits my problem..

i got a dictionary in python that looks like this:

```
 0 =     {
    awayScore = 2;
    awayTeam = "Floda BoIF";
    homeScore = 1;
    homeTeam = "SKIF Semberija";
    time = "00:00";
};
1 =     {
    awayScore = 2;
    awayTeam = "Kode IF";
    homeScore = 1;
    homeTeam = "Partille IF FK ";
    time = "01:00";
};
```

Here is the way i built it

```
dictionary[i] = {"time":time, "homeTeam":homeTeam,"homeScore":homeScore, "awayTeam":awayTeam,
     "awayScore":awayScore}
```

This is the "starting position" of all the items, Later i will get POST requests where clients sends "event" information that should be added to the dictionary. Something like this (the syntax might not be right but you will get what i want to do):

```
{
0 =     {
    awayScore = 2;
    awayTeam = "Floda BoIF";
    events =          {
        0 {
        eventType = Goal;
        name = "Muchache Johansson";
        }
        1 {
        eventType = Yellow Card;
        name = "Muchache Johansson";
        }
    };
    homeScore = 1;
    homeTeam = "SKIF Semberija";
    time = "00:00";
};
1 =     {
    awayScore = 2;
    awayTeam = "Kode IF";
    events =         {
       0 {
        eventType = Goal;
        name = "Garcia Muchache";
       }
    };
    homeScore = 1;
    homeTeam = "Partille IF FK ";
    time = "01:00";
};
```

So at first they have no events at all. Then if they don't have it you can add an event with the id 0.. Maybe another post request comes along to the same item then another event should be added with the id 1 and so on. Is this possible in a good way? Thank you for all the help..

Comment: Make the events container be a list, not a dictionary. It will still keep the events order, you'll just have to append to it. The event order_id, will just be its index in the container list

Comment: you could write that as an answer so people can se how it would look like? If its possible @Apero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite simple > you can inject element whatever you want

```
dictionary = {0 : {
        'awayScore' : 2,
        'awayTeam' : "Floda BoIF",
        'homeScore' : 1,
        'homeTeam' : "SKIF Semberija",
        'time' : "00:00",
        'events' : {}
       },
       1 : {
        'awayScore' : 2,
        'awayTeam' : "Kode IF",
        'homeScore' : 1,
        'homeTeam' : "Partille IF FK ",
        'time' : "01:00",
        'events' : {}
       }
```

And when event occure you can inject it: for instance

```
dictionary[0]['events'][0] = {
                         'eventType' : 'Goal',
                         'name' : 'Muchache Johansson',
                         }
```

If you want use list for events instead of dictionary to preserve the order without care about do it to must set it by `"events":[]` and append an event with

```
dictionary[0]['events']. append({
                         'eventType' : 'Goal',
                         'name' : 'Muchache Johansson',
                         }
```

)

Comment: Thats wonderful!! Thanks, But how do i make it so it checks how many there is in there so if i were to put a second item the id would be 1?

Comment: I add it to my answer. You could use list as @apero suggested